# How do I connect my Raspberry Pi 3 running Android Things to a wifi network?

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I have flashed my Raspberry Pi 3 with the Android Things image, I have not been able to connect it to my wifi network. I have run adb devices but I get no response.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you checked here? [Connecting Wifi](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#connecting_wi-fi)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41126958/1207921 may help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Things Not Connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984034/android-things-not-connected)

Comment: It's not fair to say this instead of helping out

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this question: [connect to Raspberry Pi 3 using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41126915/connect-to-raspberry-pi-3-using-adb)

The Raspberry Pi isn't a USB device, the USB connection is just for power, so it won't show up in `adb devices`. You have to connect it to a network first then use `adb connect`.

Comment: that was my suspicion as well... it's quite a shame that if you do not have an ethernet connection, there is no way to connect for the first time and setup WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you have to connect it to network using Ethernet and then follow the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html) using adb command to connect it to Wifi. Yeah, I know it is dumb but it is just the way it works at the moment.

And adb devices won't show anything until it is connected with TCP. RPi3 won't work as a USB slave device.

Check the details here and other stuffs.

http://pierrchen.blogspot.com.au/2017/01/a-hands-on-of-android-things-on-rpi3.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to wifi, you can connect your pi with a laptop through USB to TTL module, after that you can use putty to run the following

```
am startservice \
    -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
    -a WifiSetupService.Connect \
    -e ssid YOURWIFINAME \
    -e passphrase YOURWIFIPASSWORD
```

if you do it successfully you should be able to see your pi's ip address after running:

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

like this:

```
inet addr: 192.168.1.104 Bcast: 192.168.1.255  Mask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: what if I have a space in my ssid name?

Comment: @NoumanTahir If you have space or any special characters in your SSID then escape it by “\”.

Comment: I tried changing SSID to one without space as well...it doesn't connect, yet it's not connecting via LAN as well now, I am guessing it's something to do with my board cause sometimes it connects over the same cable and sometimes it just doent