# SSID not visible on Android Things (Raspberry Pi 3B)

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-things

I'm trying to connect my Raspberry Pi's to a WiFi network without success. Ethernet connection works flawlessly, but as I attempt to connect to WiFi using ADB as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145671/how-do-i-connect-my-raspberry-pi-3-running-android-things-to-a-wifi-network), nothing happens. I have also tried to use the Android Things Setup Utility without success as can be seen [in the terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5cUD.png).

When I try to connect through the menu option while running with a monitor connected, my particular network is not visible, **even though my work's corporate networks are visible in the same menu**. It should be noted that other devices are able to connect to the WiFi in question, and using any corporate network is not possible the project.

I have also tried

- Using a cell phone as hotspot with similar result
- Unplugging the ethernet cable when attempting to find networks(through the monitor interface)
- Changing between password/open network
- Both 2.4G and 5G
- Changing SSID from uppercase to lowercase
- Manually changing the */data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf* but cannot find any OS files on the SD card.
- Reinstalling OS image.

I'm running *Google iot_rpi3 v1.0.3*

There seems to be no documentation on this issue, has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Solved!</s> Solved again!

<s>It appears as if the Wi-Fi list in the GUI only can display at most **three** network SSID's. This lead to the corporate networks effectively 'jam' access to my Wi-Fi as the list appears to be sorted by signal strength, and my network's RSSI was weaker than the corporate one's.</s>

<s>Edit: It appears as if the device does not retain the connection setup when powered down and moved to a location where other networks are present, thus rendering any other network, with weaker signal than the top 3 present, unusuable.</s>

Edit2: Changing the router's channel from 12 to 6 seemed to do the trick. Something appears to be wonky with Raspberry Pi and channel 12. Could not update the locale either to lose the region lock.

Answer (score 4):

Did you trie 20MHz bandwidth for 2,4GHz? Some devices can not find wifi network with 40MHz bandwidth or 12 and 13 channel number.

Comment: Changing from channel 12 to channel 6 (as the visible networks were using) solved it. But I'll definitely check the bandwidth as well. Thanks for the explanation.