# Unable to connect Rainbow Hat/Raspberry pi3 with Android Things using adb

Tags: iot, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I'm using Pimoroni Rainbow-Hat Raspberry pi3 kit. I have loaded android things image on sdcard. I have power cable and ethernet cable connected.
 I can see Android things boot screen on display but i don't see the IP.

When i try to connect with adb connect Android.local it's not working(getting unknow host). I tried the ethernet cable from pi3 ethernet port to laptop , i can see the lan ip when i do ipconfig /all but when i try adb connect <-ip-:5555, still connection gets refused. but am able ping to the ip.

I am using Windows 7 OS. 
Tried turning off IP v6, Windows Firewall, rebooting host etc, still not able to connect. 
My main problem is getting the Aot device recognised on the host and load the app onto it.

I'm aware but haven't tried usb to ttl serial cable option mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41126915/connect-to-raspberry-pi-3-using-adb)

I'm familiar with Android but new to iot/Aot , any help about where i am going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set up the laptop to assign an IP address for newly connected devices? If not, plug the 2nd patch cord into the router (if any), not laptop.

Comment: under network sharing centre->ipv4-> properties, option of 'obtain an ip address automatically' is enabled. I'm guessing that should get new address right?

Comment: _"I'm guessing that should get new address right?"_ Right! From a router! So does RPi3. It should obtain the address from a router.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, i was thinking that even connecting to laptop should also work as described here ? https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/use-your-desktop-or-laptop-screen-and-keyboard-with-your-pi/ ?

Comment: I've seen this post, but couldn't make it work. So I recommend, if you have a Wifi network, connect your RPi3 to the router via Ethernet cable on the 1st boot. Then configure the Wifi settings on your Pi as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html) and connect to it over Wifi later on.

Comment: [Android Things Not Connected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988431/3290339)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i try to connect with adb connect Android.local it's not working(getting unknow host).
>
> I tried the ethernet cable from pi3 ethernet port to laptop

The Raspberry Pi is a computer in its own right.

**You need to connect the ethernet cable from the Pi3 to your *router* aka to the local network (not into your computer directly)**

The follow the steps from the [docs here and setup wifi](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html) to avoid further cable issues.

Comment: connecting to router works, there are some misleading posts on internet which claim rpi3 ethernet port to laptop works, it's just time waste.

Comment: make sure you allowed all the ports etc in the hub, in my case i connected my pi network cable to network port on router and then hdmi cable from tv to pi. that worked.