# Android Things: Connect to Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Total newbie, I have a *Raspberry Pi* and have put the *Android Things* disk image on and booted it up, but I can't connect to it from a *Windows* 10 PC running *Android Studio*, `adb.exe` via Ethernet or USB? The *Pi* screen has a green and grey "androidthings" logo, but says ***"Not Connected"***.

If I connect a USB cable and use the `adb devices` command, nothing is detected. If I connect an Ethernet cable and use `adb connect android.local` command it says `unable to connect to android.local:5555`?

I have tried two *Pi*'s with the same result.

Comment: Another similar problem with Rpi3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978167/unable-to-connect-rainbow-hat-raspberry-pi3-with-android-things-using-adb?noredirect=1#comment71148795_41978167

Comment: Yes, of course! Once I had connected the Pi to the Router I got an IP address and then adb connect <IP Address> worked.

Answer (score 5):

> The Pi screen has a green and grey "AndroidThings" logo but says "Not Connected".

The *"`Not Connected`"* message means your *RPi3* is not in your local network, which most likely caused by directly connecting the *RPi3* with your *PC / laptop*. What you should do is as follows.

---

### Connect RPi3 to your router using Ethernet cable (1 in picture)

[image]

### Reboot *RPi3*

in order to get the assigned *IP* address displayed.

### Setup Wi-Fi settings

- Connect to *RPi3* via `adb` using the *IP* displayed:

  ```
   adb connect rpi3_ip_address
  ```
- Setup Wi-fi settings [as per the docs](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#connecting_wi-fi):

  ```
   adb shell am startservice -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService -a WifiSetupService.Connect -e ssid network_SSID -e passphrase network_passcode
  ```

### Connect to *RPi3* over *Wi-Fi* (2 in picture)

```
    adb connect Android.local
```

---

*Notes*:

- *`network_SSID` and `network_passcode` are case sensitive*,
- *remove `-e passphrase network_passcode` if your network doesn't have one*

---

### What if I have neither display nor Ethernet cable?

[Connect to Serial Debug Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339) and setup *Wi-Fi* settings as above, just using `am startservice etc...` this time.

---

> If I connect a *USB* cable and use the `adb devices` command, nothing is detected.

[Micro *USB* of *RPi* isn't meant to transfer data over it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249334/3290339): a credit goes to @Fabio's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984034/android-things-not-connected/42001725#comment71517387_42001725) (*don't forget to vote it up*).

Comment: I've had success connecting to android.local with lower case, but usually it won't work with either upper or lower case (reboot helps in some cases). After months struggling I bought myself a screen so now I always get the IP - it always works. I'm still very curious to why that happens. Even commands that show IP for android.local like `dns-sd -Q Android.local` will fail me. The only option pending is scanning IP from Mac address, I'm very curious if somebody knows how to do it quickly for either Linux or Mac.

Answer (score 0):

> If I connect a USB cable and use the adb devices command, nothing is detected.

- AndroidThing device (Rpi3) will not connect through usb adb connection.
  see [not connect to adb using USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145671/how-do-i-connect-my-raspberry-pi-3-running-android-things-to-a-wifi-network?rq=1).
  Either you have to connect it through network adb i.e through ethernet or following way

Another way of connect to wifi is using serial cable.Connect serial cable to RPis GPIO.(see this [connect serial cable to RPi3](http://workshop.raspberrypiaustralia.com/usb/ttl/connecting/2014/08/31/01-connecting-to-raspberry-pi-via-usb/)) and obtain serial console.and give the following command on terminal.

```
>> su 
>>am startservice \
    -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
    -a WifiSetupService.Connect \
    -e ssid <Network_SSID> \
    -e passphrase <Network_Passcode>
```

Comment: No need to be `su`.

Comment: not any evidence but you can verify it.and most of the usb accessories are not supported in developer preview .see this https://plus.google.com/112090467711235891544/posts/78pNQa52Li2

Comment: There is official documentation, I'm not sure whether it's in preview 1 docs or Raspberry pi's, I'll have a look and try to find it. I faintly remember it wa related to not having the wires running from the connector to anywhere else. Also, I can confirm that my laptop can power the device and still adb won't work.

Comment: Micro usb port (J1) can't handle data. Here's the rpi 3 b schematic where you can see the J1 connector with only power and gnd wired in https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md.