# Android Things: Connect to Serial Debug Console

Tags: console, uart, android-things

I've been trying to connect to the [serial console of a *Raspberry Pi* 3 with *Android Things*](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#serial_debug_console) using [*USB* to *TTL* cable](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954) from my *Linux* (*Ubuntu*) machine. Despite I connected the cable as per the documentation, all I get when executing the `minicom` command is the following

[image]

with **no chance to type in any character**. So I neither can see any kernel messages nor shell into the device.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### *Linux* (*Ubuntu*)

---

*What's in?*

- *GNU Screen*
- *Minicom*

  - *minicom one-line-command (short answer)*
  - *minicom UI (long answer, detailed)*

---

### GNU Screen

Run in terminal

```
sudo screen port_name 115200
```

See below (*step 2*) to find out `port_name`, e.g `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Hit *Ctrl-A*, then *K*, then *Y* to exit `screen`. Execute `sudo apt-get install screen` if not installed.

---

### Minicom

- **Short answer**

Run in terminal

```
sudo minicom -b 115200 -o -D port_name
```

See below (*step 2*) to find out `port_name`, e.g `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Hit *Ctrl-A*, then *X* to exit `minicom`.

- **Long answer (UI)**

`minicom` should be properly configured in order to open the connection. The general steps are as follows:

1. **Install `minicom`** with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install minicom
   ```
2. [Connect *Rpi3* with your host machine using *USB-to-TTL* cable](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#serial_debug_console) and open the terminal. **Find the *tty* connections** with

   ```
   dmesg | grep -e tty
   ```

In my case I get

[image]

where `ttyUSB0` is the board.

3. **Run `minicom` and select the serial port setup** with

   ```
   sudo minicom -s
   ```

You should see

[image]

4. **Check** (or set) the **settings for the *tty*** connection. Make sure that `/dev/ttyX` corresponds to your connection, the one you get in the step 2 instead of `X`, and `Bps/Par/Bits` set as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#serial_debug_console).

Similar to

[image]

5. Now **hit Exit** and, if everything had been properly set up, the **connection should be running**. If you type the `ls` command you should see *Android Thing*'s root directory

[image]

6. For **exiting `minicom`** hit *Ctrl-A*, then hit *Q*, then *Yes*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Windows (with PuTTY)

1. [**Install *PuTTY***](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)
2. Connect the board to machine with USB-to-TTL cable and **find out the *COM* port** using [*Windows Device Manager*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager). You should look for the the one called ***USB Serial Port*** (in my case it was *COM3*).
3. **Run *PuTTY* and set it up**. Use the speed as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#serial_debug_console) (115200):

[image]

4. **Hit *Open*** and type a command in a terminal window popped up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest some troubleshooting advice based in my own experience:

**Make sure you have the Tx and Rx cables connected correctly** because all the other settings won't give you any warning, minicom would connect beautifully to the USB adapter but no info on your screen from your Pi.

I didn't use a USB to TTL like the one you are using, mine has the labels for Tx and Rx inverted on the board. Took me some time and the help of an oscilloscope to figure out what was going on.

Comment: TX and RX aren't mislabelled - you *should* connect TX to RX and RX to TX.  One serial port's transmit is the other's receive.

Comment: @fadedbee some cheap USB adapters do indeed have the TX RX pins wrongly labeled (inverted) and I don't think you took a peek at mine to support your statement.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted my comment as a potential answer, responding to your answer.  I'm sure your board is mislabelled.