# AndroidThings connected to wifi but no ip address

Tags: android, ip-address, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I have an app installed on the raspberry pi 3 using AndroidThings [preview 0.4].
IN the app code I make a connection to the wifi.  I then do a call to the wifiManager to get the connection info.

```
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid = info.getSSID();
String state = info.getSupplicantState().name();
int ipAddress = info.getIpAddress();
String ip = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
boolean enabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
String result = "wifi: " + ssid + " ip: " + ip + "  " + state + " enabled:" + enabled;
```

The result prints out as 
'wifi: "milt-att" ip: 0.0.0.0 COMPLETED enabled:true

If I restart the app several times I will eventually get a legitimate ip address.  If the SSID is not valid or the passkey to the SSID is incorrect, it tells me that it is DISCONNECTED.  Why do I not get a valid ip address once connected?

Comment: I left it sit for about 1.5 hours when I went out.  When I returned it finally had a legitimate ip address.

Comment: Again after about 1.5 hours the ipAddress is finally instantiated.  If I look at the androidThings screen it shows Wifi "milt-att" connected but no ipAddress showing.  After the 1.5 hours the ipAddress finally also shows on this screen.  I will be getting some additional raspberry pi 3 boards in the next few days and will try to see if it is related to the board and not the OS.

Comment: The only changes I made to the config.txt file as delivered in the preview was to identify the display that was connected.  I set hdmi_group=2  and hdmi_mode=28.   Just want to point out that it does eventually have a correct ip address.  It just seems to take a long time to show even though it is connected to a wifi signal.

Comment: You might [connect to serial console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554006/android-things-connect-to-serial-console) to read early boot up logs. If it helps to find out the reason, come back here and share your investigation results by answering own question :)

Comment: That requires me to go out and get a usb to TTL cable.  Isn't there a way to take the microsd card and read the logs  on there or aren't they stored on the microsd card?