# Android Things device (Raspberry Pi 3) loses internet connection (ethernet) at night/after inactivity

Tags: android, android-things

I'm working on an Android Things-App that is always running and needs an internet connection. Android Things should be great for that purpose, however I experienced a strange bug: My **Raspberry Pi 3** Model B running **Developer Preview 4** *loses its internet (ethernet) connection between 1 and 2 AM.*

Observed beahvior:

- This happens regardless of wether there is network activity or not (I've implemented a heartbeat which causes network traffic every 4 minutes but had no success)
- This always happens at night between 01:00 and 02:00 (mostly around 01:20), it never occures later or earlier
- The only way to resolve it is to turn the Raspberry off (pull the plug) and on again
- I can't get the logcat because my RPi loses its internet connection
- Unplugging and replugging the ethernet cable works fine (RPi reconnects as it should)

Does this issue affect other AT devices as well? Or is this something IP/router-specific?

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit:

The issue is filed here: https://issuetracker.google.com/37492221

---

Edit 2:

The RPi seems to fail to retrieve its IP-Address once the ethernet link is up again and thus stays disconnected. More details can be found here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63121480

Comment: have you tested another device on your network? sounds more like a router issue

Comment: Maybe a provider maitainance work happening within the period?

Comment: @Blundell I haven't tried any other devices yet... Onik: Good point, but why is the connection not re-established at some later point? I will do some research about my router/provider

Comment: _"I can't get the logcat because my RPi loses its internet connection"_. You can if also the [debug console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339) is connected.

Comment: @onik Sadly, I don't own such a cable, but someone else does and he confirmed, that the RPi does not properly reconnect to the network after a network failure. He filed a new issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63121480