# Android Things: Intel Edison: Using USB and Debugging

Tags: intel, android-things, intel-edison

Has anyone had any luck using USB debugging with an Edison while also using a USB peripheral? It looks like you have to use the switch to activate the bigger USB port, which also cuts off the debugging port. I'm trying to use a USB camera, but can't see the debugger info to actually figure out what's not correct. I also get a connection refused when attempting to use adb connect on the wifi ip.

Comment: If reading logs over the serial debug console is enough for you and you run into some obstacle connecting to it, you might look at a couple of solutions: using [`PuTTY` (Windows) and both `GNU Screen` and `Minicom` (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339)

Answer (score 4):

> It looks like you have to use the switch to activate the bigger USB port, which also cuts off the debugging port.

Correct, only one port can be active at a time between the USB Host and USB OTG on the Edison. If you just need access to logs for debugging, connect another USB cable for the serial debug console as described on the [Android Things Edison](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/edison.html#serial_debug_console) page. This will give you shell access and you can run `logcat`.

> I'm trying to use a USB camera, but can't see the debugger info to actually figure out what's not correct.

It's worth noting that USB cameras are not supported in the current preview release. It's unlikely that the device will be recognized as a camera through the APIs, though you may still be able to access it as a raw USB device if you wish.

> I also get a connection refused when attempting to use adb connect on the wifi ip.

The Edison defaults to USB mode for ADB, but you should be able to set it to TCP mode to connect over the network (much like an Android phone):

```
$ adb tcpip 5555
$ adb connect <ip address>:5555
```

…or the following, which should persist the configuration across a reboot:

```
$ adb root
$ adb shell setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555
$ adb reboot
$ adb wait-for-device
$ adb connect <ip address>:5555
```

Comment: I still cannot connect to Android Things device.  Get an error: **unable to connect to Android.local:5555: Connection refused**