# Android Things adb: not found

Tags: adb, android-things

When trying to execute `./adb shell` or `adb shell` being connected to *Android Things* via [serial console](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#serial_debug_console) I get `./adb: not found` and `adb: not found` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am connected via serial port to my raspberry 3

[Once you got serial console connected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339) you're already "`shell`"-ed in, meaning there is no need to execute `adb` for (*further*) connection.

Moreover, the `adb` binary is missing under `/system/bin` of *Android Things* (*at least by now*). This is the reason why you get `adb: not found`.

Summing up, when connected to serial console you should execute commands *without `adb` or `adb shell`*.