# Debugging corrupted Android Things OS?

Tags: android-things

**Background:** We are looking to release a commercial product based on the Android Things OS and Pi 3 hardware.  The OS seems to become corrupt over time.  Usually after several weeks of continuous testing. By corrupt, the Android screen will no longer appear on startup and putting SD into new hardware does not remedy.  We are using an application Factory Image base on the 0.5.1-devpreview created in the Console.
**My question: Is there a way to debug or monitor what caused this state in the OS? Direct serial connection?**

Comment: _"Is there a way to debug or monitor what caused this state in the OS?"_ It probably the SD card that got corrupted (not OS).

Comment: Try another SD card.

Comment: I was going to ask, how often have you flashed that SD card?

Comment: Flashed maybe 4 times max then deployed into field for testing.  We have new cards deployed.  I'll update this thread on outcome.  I just wish there was a way to definitively identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to clean the sd card with the [diskpart command](https://www.howtogeek.com/235824/how-to-clean-a-flash-drive-sd-card-or-internal-drive-to-fix-partition-and-capacity-problems/) and start again from scratch.

And to debug, maybe a [USB to TTL cable](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954) may help. As explained [here](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html).

Regards!

Comment: @Greg, some extra info to the answer... The [official reference](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html) wasn't helpful for me in connecting to serial console. I posted (hopefully more detailed) description in [Android Things: Connect to Serial Debug Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339)