# Which external Display device should I used to Check Android things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, ip, raspberry-pi3, android-things

Actually, I don't have an external TFT Display or T.v which supported Android operating system. I need to know the IP address that is assigned to my raspberry pi 3 after connecting to the router. I am using Android thing operating System in raspberry pi and trying to find the IP address without using any TFT or Android Supported T.V. So, I tried to use on the projector but OS does not load on it. Please, any way/hack would be helpful !!

Comment: One of the options in getting Pi's IP address is to [Connect to Serial Debug Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339) (in case you have [_USB_ to _TTL_ cable](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to find the raspberry Pi's ip address using the IP lease tables on your router. Most routers will display this information if you log into their web interfaces.

Which operating system is the raspberry pi running?

You could do something like [this](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/how-to-raspberry-pi-headless-setup/)

Comment: This is Raspberry Pi 3  running on Android things operating system. Is there any way to provide the static IP to this Raspberry Pi to use for the first time.

Comment: Suppose my laptop is connected to the wifi network and then I connect my raspberry pi 3 to my laptop through ethernet. Then by anyways can I get the IP address that was assigned to my raspberry pi without using any external screen. I have just my laptop screen.

Comment: I can't find a way of doing this without a screen, mate. I think your best bet is to find a friend with a screen you can use. Failing that, I'm sure there are some cheap screens available at flee markets or online.

Comment: NO problem this problem is resolved now, I just checked the Android things site again and download the new **android-things-setup-utility**, and I get the router with configured Ip address, Then I just connect my Raspberry Pi 3 to the router and it simply assigns the new IP address to my pi, And everything working properly, I also able to deploy my android project to raspberry pi 3 through `adb connect <ip address>`, But now I am facing the new issues i.e. to connect my raspberry pi to wifi network and how I access my pi_camera, So I can view the display directly on my laptop.

Comment: I recommend you make a new question for that, as I have no idea :P

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, It is done now and, I will be sharing my image recognition project with tensorflow, soon I will be published my project with all details on [link](https://www.hackster.io). I will update here after it will be published.