# Where can be found WiFi MAC address on RPi3 with Android Things?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-wifi, mac-address, android-things

Is there any possibility to found WiFi (and Ethernet also) MAC address on Raspberry Pi 3 with Android Things Developer Preview 7 BEFORE it connected to WiFi (or Ethernet) network?

Comment: How about [Connecting to Serial Debug Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339) and executing `ifconfig` or `netcfg`

Comment: @Onik Good suggestion and seems to be the only possible one. It is a pity that MAC not shown at Settings page...

Comment: do you mind I answer?

Comment: @Onik I think - yes, if someone else wouldn't offer a "secret" key combination. I didn't test. I got MAC address via WiFi router web interface.

Comment: Why don't you try connecting Pi to normal network which require no static ip and password? if it gets connected to a wifi then its easy to find the MAC from connected devices list

Comment: @HarishJose See above comment: " I got MAC address via WiFi router web interface." - it's actually the same. But it will be good, if MAC was shown on home screen/network settings.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Yeah. I agree. Also there is no option for setting the DHCP for a wifi connection

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the solution to your question. This is very important where we are using the Rasberry Pi in an location where the internet connectivity will be provided with a static ip with gateway setup inside the device or registering the device mac address on the firewall settings.

So what to do?

```
connect the Rasberry Pi to a wifi network where there is no static ip settings required
(Say your mobile phone's hotspot). 

Then you can find the MAC Address of the RPi from the connected devices list.
```

This will help you.