# Raspberry Pi 3 androidthing with rpi3 devpreview 4 os - Not connected

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things

I have install OS in SD card and after installation OS is boot successfully but display below message every time:

http://prntscr.com/fbhj3j

I did not connect LAN cable raspberry board.

If this issue is because I cannot connect internet using wifi? If yes, how?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41984034/6950238) question and answers.

Comment: Thanks but in my display no error similar to those error. in that post error are no Wifi connection and no Ethernet connection but mine is different.

Comment: _"in that post error are no Wifi connection and no Ethernet connection but mine is different"_ It does not matter those messages vary with Dev Preview versions, but the solution keeps being the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Things Not Connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984034/android-things-not-connected)

Answer (score 0):

You need to continue to follow the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html

**A Raspberry Pi will not connect to the Wifi if you have not first connected to an ethernet lan cable first. (Once you are connected via ethernet you then can configure the wifi and finally remove the ethernet cable).**

So you are up to this step:

> Connect an Ethernet cable to your local network.

When this is connected, your screen will show the IP address of the Raspberyy Pi on your local network