# Android Things: ADB over USB on Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, adb, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I'm playing with *Raspberry Pi 3 Model B* and *Android Things*. I was able to [configure](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html) everything (connect *Pi* over *Ethernet*, then reconnect over *Wi-Fi* with `Android.local`) and debug the app. However it's not convenient sometimes to debug over *Wi-Fi* when I travel and I have to change *Wi-Fi* networks or don't have *Wi-Fi* connection at all.

I know there is [serial debug console](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#serial_debug_console), but it seems to be for getting logs and shell commands, not for debugging.

Any chance to have direct debugging over *USB* cable just like any other *Android* device like smartphone/tablet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NXP i.MX7D development board has the same pins as the Raspberry Pi for development, however it uses USB-C for power and ADB.

Highly recommend it over the Raspberry Pi

https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d.html

[image]
<sub>(source: [android.com](https://developer.android.com/things/images/nxp-pico7-board.png))</sub>

Comment: wired ADB is not supported on the Raspberry Pi, so while yes thats the only limitation - it cannot be guaranteed more issues may not arise in the future because its not supported

Answer (score 6):

> How to debug Android Things device over USB?

Briefly: **you can't** do it with *Raspberry Pi*.

### Why not?

Let's look at the [pin specification of *Raspberry Pi* micro *USB* (J1)](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings):

[image]

where

- 1: **power**
- 2: **D-** (data out), not connected
- 3: **D+** (data in), not connected
- 4: **NC**, not connected
- 5: **GND** (ground)

So summing up the above said: **no data pin connection - no `adb`**. You can only power your *RPi* over micro *USB*.

> Any chance to have direct debugging over USB cable just like any other Android device like smartphone/tablet?

Use another board. In fact, **any board that has *USB OTG* and is supported by *Android Things* would allow debugging over *USB***, just as a "regular" smartphone/tablet.

And ironically, by the time of this writing, all the [supported hardware platforms](https://developer.android.com/things#hardware_platforms) would fit except for *Raspberry Pi* :)

Comment: I have the Edison & NXP both support usb adb :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to setup Wi-Fi access point on your laptop and allow the Pi to connect to it. I have not tested it but it should work.