# How can i connect android thing (Raspberry pi) to android studio using USB to UART(Usb to ttl)

Tags: raspberry-pi3, uart, android-things

Hi i have one **uart or usb to ttl cable** , now i want to connect android thing (Raspberry Pi) to my android Studio for serial debugging , **Without using wireless Or wired network connection with Android thing board**. But when i run android thing app from android studio , android thing board didn't shown.

[image]

Comment: [Android Things: ADB over USB on Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44241668/3290339)

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi/Android Things does not support ADB over UART serial.

Comment: @MaYuR Solanki, in addition to the Nick's answer, when [connected to serial console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339) you can only read your app's logs (with `logcat`) and, of course, do all the other `shell` "stuff".

Comment: https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart.html