# Run a hello word project from android studio on a raspberry pi

Tags: adb, raspberry-pi3, iot, android-things

I am new to IoT technology and I am trying to run a hello word project from android studio to a raspberry pi.

I followed the steps from this tutorial: [Hello World com Raspberry Pi 3 usando Android Things](https://medium.com/android-dev-br/hello-world-com-raspberry-pi-3-usando-android-things-2b10fa6dc21d). But I am stuck at the step in which I have to connect the raspberry pi with adb.

The connection failed all the time. I connected the raspberry pi with an USB cable to my laptop and with an Ethernet cable for the wired network.

Did anyone had the same problem?

I put here an image with the errors

[image]

Comment: You cannot have [ADB over USB on Raspberry Pi 3B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249334/3290339)

Comment: Also take a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi).

Comment: Tried `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` on the host machine?

Comment: I did the steps with the android-things-setup-utility as in the link you mentioned, but at some point it doesn't work. This is the error: Failed connecting to Android device: unable to connect to Android.local:5555: cannot resolve host 'Android.local' and port 5555: No such host is known. (11001)

Comment: Might be a router issue. Try connecting Pi over LAN directly (if possible), not WiFi.

Comment: Yes, I also tried with adb kill-server and adb start-server. I put the raspberry pi ip address in the command adb connect <ip_raspberry>, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: If utility can't connect using Android.local (for me it never worked) the error message should look like the following:

"Failed connecting to Android device: unable to connect to Android.local:5555: Operation timed out

Could not automatically find your Raspberry Pi. We will need you to enter its IP address.
One way to find it is to plug your Raspberry Pi to a monitor and reboot. Once it has booted, it will show its IP.
Once you are ready, enter the IP of your Raspberry Pi:"

Comment: if the Android Things is connected to ethernet and in the same network as your laptop, you should be able to use adb connect anf then the ip.
The simplest way of knowing the IP of your Android Things is to connect a monitor and mouse and check it on the device.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is an official documentation how to start with the Raspberry PI
https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi

I guess that you haven't set up your raspberry properly. The key points there are:

- flash the SD-card using utility
- setup wifi using utility
  The utility could be found [here](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi#flash-at)

After that you are going to be able to connect over wifi

Comment: WiFi is not necessary to connect via adb as long as he uses ethernet (which he is using)