# Can't use Serial debug console on Raspberry pi 3B Android Things

Tags: adb, raspberry-pi3, logcat, android-things

I am trying to connect my Raspberry pi 3B which has Android Things installed to my PC using the Serial debug cable. I connected it as instructed [Here](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html#serial-console) and followed the below steps using PUTTY on Windows 10.

N.B: Same issue is with the Android **Emteria** version for Raspberry pi 3B.

[image]

[image]

**All I get is an empty console window, which I can't even type into. The device is not seen either in Android studio or using the ADB tool**
[image]

**I am not sure about which Com to use, here's my device manager:**
[image]

---

### Note

I am able to connect the device using Wifi, and ADB using this command:

```
adb connect <ip address>
```

and I install apps normally and they work fine using Android Studio.

---

**Now, I want to make the Serial debug method work, and will it allow me to run my apps from Android studio + see the Logcat logs? Plz review my above mentioned steps and tell me if I am missing something.**

Comment: It won't allow you to run apps from _Android Studio_, but it does allow to see log messages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44241668/1778421

Answer (score 0):

From your device manager, it looks like the driver for your serial cable may not be installed correctly.

Assuming you are using the recommended cable from Adafruit, you need to install the proper drivers for Windows. Try downloading the Silicon Labs drivers (http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/Software/CP210x_Windows_Drivers.zip) and installing those. You may need to restart your computer to complete the installation.

Otherwise, if it's a Cypress cable,  you may need to update the Cypress UCM Client Peripheral Driver that your device manager is showing an error on. Right click on that and select update driver.

Once your serial cable is installed properly and recognized by Windows, you should be able to connect to your Pi as instructed.