# I can't do android things image after console option is used to build a new image

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I stay trying this: https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html

I build a new image in android things console option.

I put a image in raspberry pi 3, but when I run adb devices, my new rpi 3 android things device never appears

[image: `enter]

[image]
[image: enter image here]

[image]

[image: sd card final recording image]

***The light of the ethernet cable attached in the raspberry pi 3 not flash***

Help me please

SOLVED w I change sd card to class 10 sd

Comment: [Android Things: Connect to Raspberry Pi 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988431/3290339)

Comment: Adb on the pi can only be used guys network. Have you plugged the ethernet cable?

Comment: Onik I can't see a  green and grey "AndroidThings" logo              shalafi : Yes, I do

Comment: _"I can't see a green and grey Android Things logo"_. Booting successfully or not does not depend on Ethernet. There must be something else going on that prevents the OS to boot correctly. [Connect to debug console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554006/3290339) at look at `dmesg` and perhaps `logcat` messages.

Comment: Your SD card needs to be class 10. Did you verify that?

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED when I change sd card to class 10 sd

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments you need to connect to adb via your network. So connect your RPI to the network via ethernet cable and find its ip addr. For example you might find it this way:

```
$ nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

Then, say you see the device IP as 192.168.1.228. Connect to adb via the network like this:

```
$ adb connect 192.168.1.228
connected to 192.168.1.228:5555
```

At this point you should be able to validate your connection:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.1.228:5555    device
```

Comment: please take a look at the first recently uploaded photo. when I insert another sd card in raspberry (with raspbian)  i  no have  problem with ethernet however when I insert the card created via android things console the system is not finding the ethernet